# Blazor case-changes DOM tags

Tags: html, svg, clip-path, blazor

I'm using blazor to generate SVG items on a page.  This works great except when I am trying to create a `<clipPath>` tag.  Blazor is case-changing it to `<clippath>` which is not an accepted SVG tag and therefore does nothing.

Is there a way to get Blazor to keep the case of my tags intact?

**Edit: Sample Code**

```
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <g clip-path="url(#myClip)">
    <rect width="200" height="200" fill="red"></rect>
    <clipPath id="myClip">
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="none"></circle>
    </clipPath>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I don't think the case is the problem...

Comment: @Issac yes this is the problem. I have tested this.  If you use some sort of editor like codepen or jsfiddle or even notepad and purposefully enter `<clippath>`  when they generate the code it will auto correct it to `<clipPath>`.  However, Blazor is doing the opposite for me.  So if you use the inspector to change you `<clipPath>` to `<clippath>` you will notice that it no longer works.  This is why I need to get Blazor to leave it as `<clipPath>`

Comment: please do this: 1. Go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath 2. Click on the button "Open in CodePen" to see a relevant sample. Now change clipPath to clippath and see whether the sample still works or not...

Comment: @Issac As I said before, if you edit "clipPath" to "clippath" in codepen, the browser figures it out for you and corrects it back to "clipPath".  You can confirm this by opening the inspector after making the change and seeing that it is still "clipPath".  But Blazor is actually taking my "clipPath" and changing it to "clippath" and the browser is not correcting it back.  Take the sample code I just added and add it to a Blazor component in a Blazor app and you will see what I mean.  Then take it and plug it into codepen so you can see the difference.

Comment: @JoeHigley I suspect Blazor is therefore creating elements in the HTML namespace rather than the SVG namespace.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm not sure I follow what this means.

Comment: This is a known issue (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5613) in Blazor. You may be able to work around it if you can render the svg once, then only manipulate it through CSS properties. At least, in 0.6.0 the initial render didn't lower case everything, but subsequent changes did.

Comment: @JoeHigley https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I reported this on the .Net github and it is now a confirmed bug.  It also looks like they've prioritized the fix to be part of the .Net Core 3.0 milestone.  Here's a link to the issue for anyone else who wants to follow it.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6507